# NSDictionary not looping through correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSDictionary created by the AFNetworking class, but now I want to convert that NSDictionary into an array of objects of a class that I made.  I have tried using the for-in loop as follows:

```
    for (NSDictionary *item in results)
        [_masterList addObject:[[MyObject alloc]initWithType:[item objectForKey:@"type"];
```

`results` by the way is my NSDictionary.  There are no syntax errors, but when I run my program, nothing comes up.  I tried `NSLog`-ing in the for-in, but didn't get anything, which means that the loop does not even run once.  I'm pretty sure the NSDictionary is full, because I `NSLog`ed the result during the AFNetworking process, and it was full:

`(
        {
        address = "Sample Address";
    }
)`

Anyone have any ideas that I could use?  Please express in the comments if I should add any more code.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post the log of `results`?

Comment: I already posted the log.

Comment: What's the log of `_masterList` after the `for` loop?

Comment: Like I stated in my question, _masterList is empty.

Comment: @JackThomas and what does the `NSLog` show? I'm trying to rule out that `_masterList` is `nil`.

Comment: OK, well I just `NSLog`ged it, and it says "0 objects"

Comment: @JackThomas : `results` has "0 objects"?

Comment: No, `_masterList` has "0 objects"

Comment: @JackThomas that's not how arrays log; an empty array is logged literally as `()` (with a newline between the brackets).

Comment: I... it doesn't seem like it does...

Answer (score 0):

There are no key `type`, change it to `address`

```
for (NSDictionary *item in results)
    [_masterList addObject:[[MyObject alloc]initWithType:[item objectForKey:@"address"];
```

Comment: Um... what's the difference between that and my code?

Comment: @JackThomas what did you change?

Comment: @JackThomas Did you try my answer? And what happen?

Comment: @JackThomas I don't understand what do you mean. Just need to change `type` to `address` at `[_masterList addObject:[[MyObject alloc]initWithType:[item objectForKey:@"type"];`

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but too big for a comment: you've made a mistake other than in the code presented. Try:

```
NSArray *results = @[
    @{
        @"address": @"Sample Address"
    }
];

NSLog(@"%@", results);

for (NSDictionary *item in results)
    NSLog(@"%@ (%@)", item, [item objectForKey:@"address"]);
```

Output is:

```
2015-11-10 23:20:22.713 Untitled[1564:1904151] (
        {
        address = "Sample Address";
    }
)
2015-11-10 23:20:22.715 Untitled[1564:1904151] {
    address = "Sample Address";
} (Sample Address)
```

So, definitely the same dictionary, then the same iteration code, with correct results.

---

Addendum, which may or may not be helpful: one of the things Apple supplies to take advantage of Objective-C's reflective runtime is key-value coding which, assuming your properties obey certain rules, allows them to be written to by name. If you had a dictionary you wanted to commute to an object, and had performed suitable validation, then you might:

```
NSDictionary *inputDictionary = ... whatever ...
SomeObject *target = [[SomeObject alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in inputDictionary)
    [target setValue:inputDictionary[key] forKey:key];
```

In contrast to Objective-C norms but consistently with most modern languages, that'll raise an exception if the key doesn't exist as a property on `target`. So in production code you probably want at least a try/catch block if the dictionary is coming from afar.

Comment: `results` is not an NSArray; it is declared as an NSDictionary

Comment: @JackThomas then your problem is somewhere in your incorrect knowledge about the network result. The thing you've printed in your question is an array. Try `NSLog(@"%@", [results class])` and see for yourself.

Comment: Ahh... I see.  How then would I loop through an NSDictionary through a for-in fast enumeration loop?

Comment: It's a hassle in Objective-C as there are no tuples; looping through an `NSDictionary` is equivalent to looping through `[dictionary allKeys]` — if it was originally JSON then all the keys are definitely strings, so you'll iterate through a bunch of strings that are the keys of the dictionary. You'll then need to `[dictionary objectForKey:key]` (or just `dictionary[key]`) to look up values. But your logged version of `results` in the original question is _definitely_ an array.

Comment: Hmm... OK then.  So what would your algorithm be to transfer an NSDictionary into an array of objects of a class?  The names of the members of the class are the same as the keys, and there are no null values.

Comment: @JackThomas assuming the members are key-value coding compliant, which they almost certainly are (and definitely are if you've just declared `@property`s) then you can use the key-value coding `setValue:forKey:`. I'll write it up.

Comment: Ahh... Thanks a bunch, sir.

Comment: Wow... so if my key in the NSDictionary is `hello`, it will look for a property called `hello` in my class?  Apple thinks of the smartest things :)

Comment: Yeah... that for loop is still not running.

Comment: Then `inputDictionary` is `nil` or has no keys, or your test for whether the for loop is working is invalid.

Comment: OK, I finally found the problem.  I created `results` using a `__block` type specifier.  I change that in the AFNetworking function, and all is well in there, but when the function exits, my variable stays empty.  What do you think I should do now?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`results` is a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` of dictionaries? If it is `NSDictionary` then you must loop like this:

```
// loop through each key in dictionary
// let say your key type is NSString
for (NSString* key in results) {

    // access your object for key here
    NSLog(@"%@", results[key]);
}
```

Comment: Ahh... OK.  What does results[key] return by the way?

Comment: Just short version of `[result objectForKey:key]`